# How can I use jUnit with J2EE 1.4 if annotations are not supported?

Tags: testing, jakarta-ee, junit

how to use junit for j2ee 1.4 application client

Comment: Note the problem is Java 1.4 not JEE 1.4.  And Constantiner is correct to use JUnit 3.8

Answer (score 1):

Just use jUnit 3.8.x instead of jUnit4.